# How do I pass a property of Datatemplate's Datatype to Caliburn.Micros Message.Attach?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I'm currently in the process of implementing a menu navigation system for a group project. We're using Caliburn.Micro and the MVVM pattern.

The menu is located in the `ShellView.xaml` and is based on a `List<NavigationMenuItem>` that has been filtered using the Role property.

```
public class NavigationMenuItem
    {
        public IScreen ViewModel { get; set; }
        public string IconPath { get; set; }

        public string Role { get; set; }

        public NavigationMenuItem(IScreen viewModel, string iconPath, string role)
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;
            IconPath = iconPath;
            Role = role;
        }
    }
```

The menu is displaying just fine, but now I want to pass the ViewModel-property to a method in the `ShellViewModel.cs`, such that I can activate a view change. This is how the `ShellView.xaml` looks so far:

```
<Window
    x:Class="P3GG.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:P3GG.Views"
    xmlns:models="clr-namespace:P3GG.Models"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:templates="clr-namespace:P3GG.Templates"
     xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    Title="Title"
    Width="800"
    Height="600"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Visibility="{Binding SidebarIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed}"
                 Grid.Column="0"
                 Background="#333333"
                 x:Name="NavigationMenu">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="models:NavigationMenuItem">
                    <Button cal:Message.Attach="Handle( <!-- pass content of NavigationMenuItem.ViewModel --> )" Style="{StaticResource BtnSidebar}">
                        <Image Margin="20" Source="{Binding IconPath}"/>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentControl  Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `ShellViewModel.cs` currently contains two Handle methods:

```
public void Handle(Screen screen)
public void Handle(User user)
```

How do I pass the ViewModel property of a given `NavigationMenu` to the `Handle(Screen)` method?

**EDIT**
Added Handle method per request

```
public void Handle(Screen screen)
        {
            if (screen is LoginViewModel)
            {
                SidebarIsVisible = false;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SidebarIsVisible);
            }
            else
            {
                SidebarIsVisible = true;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SidebarIsVisible);
            }
            ActivateItem(screen);
        }
```

Comment: do you mean "how do I *pass*" instead of *parse*?

Comment: I sure do. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: hum, the Handle  is for EventAgregator, could you show your shellview/shellviewmodel code?

Comment: I added the full method to the OP. I'm just using the aggregator to pass around screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this, as explained [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet):

```cs
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Handle($dataContext)]" Style="{StaticResource BtnSidebar}">
    <Image Margin="20" Source="{Binding IconPath}"/>
</Button>
```

This will pass the full view model (`DataContext`) to your handler.

To pass a *specific property of your view model*, use the long syntax as indicated [here](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/cheat-sheet):

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource BtnSidebar}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers> 
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"> 
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Handle"> 
               <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ViewModel}" /> 
            </cal:ActionMessage> 
        </i:EventTrigger> 
    </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
    <Image Margin="20" Source="{Binding IconPath}"/>
</Button>
```

with `i` defined as

```xml
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

You could also change the `DataContext` property of the `Button` to the property of interest, like:

```cs
<Button DataContext="{Binding ViewModel}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Handle($dataContext)]" Style="{StaticResource BtnSidebar}">
    <Image Margin="20" Source="{Binding IconPath}"/>
</Button>
```

so only the correct property gets passed to your hendler, but this feels like a hack.
On click, this will hand-over the `DataContext` of the `Button` as parameter of your `Handle` method, which should be a `NavigationMenuItem`.

Comment: That works, but I want to pass the specific property of the item.

Comment: Alright, I'm getting somewhere, but the object send by the actionMessage is seemingly not of type "Screen". I can receive it by creating a Handle(object value) and then recast it. Any ideas on how to get the data type right?

Comment: Can you show the code of your `NavigationMenuItem` class? Maybe your `ViewModel` property is not of type `Screen`? What is the actual type you receive? Without more info it's difficult to help.